# Accessing a CSV file from another domain

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

A customer wants to display a list of addresses on his website (which changes regularily). The CMS behind that website does not offer any functions to do so. Also I can't access the file system behind that website and neither can i write server side code.

However, the customer has got another webspace we can use. So the best solution we came up with was that he just places a CSV file on his webspace which I can access and display from the original website via AJAX.
But if I try to do that, i get the following error:

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

The customer isn't able to add this header. Is there any way i can access this CSV file OR any other solution i fail to see?

Answer (score 0):

You could embed around (maybe via a simple php file) a jsonp like function call and embed the file with simple script tags.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the customer save the address list as an image, which can be hotlinked without the cross-origin policy getting in the way.

Alternatively you can explain to the customer that you're not a wizard, and need a modicum of accommodation so that you actually can do your job. Would you ask your mechanic to repair your car without giving access to the engine?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, i know i have quite much limitations but the customer can't change it. However, do you mean by 'save the address list as an image' actually using a picture that is displayed directly? Or do you mean making the CSV file looking like a picture to the browser in order to get around the cross-origin policy? Since the customer wants to change that list regularily and the data needs to be processed (sorting, etc.) unfortunately an actual image is not an option.

Comment: I meant literally saving it as an image. Which would be ridiculous, but I don't believe there's any other way with the limitations your client impose upon you. If neither of these servers can be configured in any way you'll have to set up a new one.